# Probability Density function help... $(X,Y) \sim f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}$ where $I = (0 < y < x < 1 )$ ....

Tags: probability

a) show that $f(x,y)$ is a probability density function.

b) $f_Y (y\mid X=x_0) =$ ? (for what $y$ is this the correct "formula"?)

c) $f_Y (y) = $ ?

My ideas:

a) Clearly in our $I$ this is positive and when it is not in $I$ it is $0$.
Then, do I need to show that $\int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{1}{x} \, dy \, dx = 1$ ?

b) $f_Y (y\mid X=x_0) = \frac{1}{x_0} \, I(0 < y < x_0)$?

c) $f_Y(y) = \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x}dx = -log(y)$ for $\,0<y<1$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: b) The conditional density is $0$ lots of places. It is $\frac{1}{x_0}$ for $0\lt y\lt x_0$. (Here $0\lt x_0\lt 1$.) c) "Integrate out" $x$. In the interesting part, $x$ goes from $y$ to $1$.

Comment: You have $x$ going from $0$ to $y$, but it should be from $y$ to $1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your limits of integration for (a) are wrong:  the region of integration is specified by $0 < y < x < 1$, so the limits should be $$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=y}^1 f \, dx \, dy$$ or equivalently, $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^x f \, dy \, dx.$$  For (b), use your intuition:  if $X = x_0$, that means $f_Y(y \mid X = x_0)$ is the conditional density with support $0 < y < x_0$, and on this interval, the density is proportional to the likelihood $f(x_0,y) = 1/x_0$,. which is **uniform**.  All you need to do is figure out what the area under the likelihood is as a function of $x_0$, and divide by this value in order to obtain a true conditional density that integrates to $1$ on $0 < y < x_0$.

Comment: could you possibly expand upon what you stated at the end with figuring out the area under the likelihood is as a function of $x_0$ ? I don't fully understand. Thanks!